# What does "new block detected on network before long poll" mean?

Tags: mining-pools, dogecoin, terminology

I'm new to mining and I'm mining doge coins. My mining client reported

```
new block detected on network before longpoll
```

but it doesn't seem like I'm actually mining anything. What does this mean?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It means a block has been found and what your currently mining is the past block.

Comment: It can mean that your miner is too slow for the coin you're mining. For example, if it takes you 30 seconds to finish a work unit and you can't abort a work unit in progress, that's about a 3% waste with Bitcoin, but a 25% waste with Dogecoin.